# How to write an HTML Snippet that duplicates the text within a paragraph each time it's double clicked?

Tags: html, dom

I want to write a snippet to get something as below:

(Starting): Text

(After one double clicks) Text Text

(After two double clicks) Text Text Text Text

(After three double clicks) Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

My code only allow me to duplicate once when I double click it. How to make it duplicate every time when i double click it? Please help!! Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button ondblclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    var str = "This is a paragraph.";
    var res = str.concat(str);
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = res;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is overwriting the content of the div (#results) each time you call the function - so there will only ever be able to be the one double statement- so you need to get the current text - add the new text to that and set the innerHTML to that combined value.

```js
function myFunction(){
    var str = "This is a paragraph.";
    var res = str.concat(str);
    var currentText = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = currentText + res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <button ondblclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome - happy to help. If this solution solves your issue - please click the accepted checkbox so that other users know the issue has been resolved. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/2pzmo58t/1/

Instead of using `.innerHTML`, you'd use `.append()`.